# Leap Frog/Multi step method stability

Tags: numerical-methods, finite-differences, stability-theory, finite-difference-methods

**Background**

The finite difference Euler method is

\begin{eqnarray}
y_{n+1} &=& T(y_n,t_n)\\
 &=& y_{n} + hf(y_n,t_n).
\end{eqnarray}

Then for some perturbation $\delta$

\begin{eqnarray}
y_{n+1} + \delta_{n+1} &=& T(y_{n} + \delta_{n},t_n)\\
 &=& y_{n} + 2hf(y_n,t_n) + \delta_{n}\frac{\partial T(y_n,t_n)}{\partial y_n}
\end{eqnarray}

giving a growth factor of

\begin{eqnarray}
g_{n} &=& \frac{\partial T(y_n,t_n)}{\partial y_n}
\end{eqnarray}

where stability requires $|g_n| < 1$.

For second order Runge-Kutta (RK2) methods we have

\begin{eqnarray}
y_{n+1/2} &=& \frac{h}{2}f(y_n,t_n),\\
y_{n+1} &=& hf(y_{n+1/2},t_{n+1/2})\\[10pt]
g_n &=& \frac{\partial y_{n+1/2}}{\partial y_n}\\
 &=& 1 + h\frac{\partial f(y_{n+1/2},t_{n+1/2})}{\partial y_{n+1/2}}\bigg[1+\frac{h}{2}\frac{\partial f(y_n,t_n)}{\partial y_n}\bigg]
\end{eqnarray}

For a small $h$ the below assumption gives growth in terms of the complex plane $\Delta$

\begin{eqnarray}
\Delta &=& h\frac{\partial f(y_n,t_n)}{\partial y_n}\\
 &\approx& h\frac{\partial f(y_{n+1/2},t_{n+1/2})}{\partial y_{n+1/2}}\\[10pt]
g_n &=& 1 + \Delta + \frac{\Delta^2}{2}.
\end{eqnarray}

**Question**

For the leap frog method

\begin{eqnarray}
y_{n+1} &=& y_{n-1} + 2hf(y_n,t_n)
\end{eqnarray}

w.r.t. the complex plane $\Delta$, why is the stability

\begin{eqnarray}
g_n^2 &=& 1 + 2\Delta g_n?
\end{eqnarray}

I got the following

\begin{eqnarray}
g_n &=& \frac{\partial y_{n+1}}{\partial y_n}\\
 &=& \frac{\partial y_{n-1}}{\partial y_n} + 2h\frac{\partial f(y_{n},t_n)}{\partial y_n}\\
 &=& 1 + 2h\frac{\partial f(y_{n},t_n)}{\partial y_n}\\[10pt]
\Delta &=& h\frac{\partial f(y_{n},t_n)}{\partial y_n}\\[10pt]
\Rightarrow g_n &=& 1 + 2\Delta.
\end{eqnarray}

I am unsure where the extra $g_n$ comes from on either side, as multiplying both sides by $g_n$ would give $g_n^2 = g_n + 2\Delta g_n$.

Comment: What does $T$ represent? Also, I think you either used a central difference formula for a first derivative in the first line, in case the RHS should have a stand alone $y_{n-1}$ not $y_{n}$, or you used a Forward Euler as you claim in which case there should be no $2$ in front of the $f(t_{n}, y_{n})$.

Comment: Yes corrected to remove 2 from first line. $T$ is the forward step, so is this where the extra $g$ comes from as the leap frog is essentially two forward steps from $(n-1) \rightarrow (n+1)$?